# Call js webscript from Java webscript in Alfresco

Tags: java, javascript, alfresco, web-scripting

I have a problem.  I need execute js webscript from Java webscript. I know, how do it:

```
req.getRuntime().getContainer().getRegistry().getWebScript("com/home/testJs/testJs.get").execute(req, res)
```

, but how to construct the new WebScriptRequest object? I need do it for rewrite request path. It's a really problem for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should use [WebScriptRequestURLImpl](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.M3/spring-webscripts/spring-webscripts/apidocs/org/springframework/extensions/webscripts/WebScriptRequestURLImpl.html). Without any other detail, it's hard go any deeper.

That said, it's in general a bad idea to go through yet another HTTP call to yourself to fix your problem, it's basically an indication of poor modularization or lack of code reuse.

I'd rather move the piece of code that's common in both the JS and Java web scripts flows to be an [Action](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions), which you could invoke from both places without having to repackage the input parameters, or worse send them via HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But now i have another problem. If i have next js webscript mapping - "/testUrl/{testVar1}/{testVar2}" and next mapping for Java webscript, which called js webscript - "/testUrl2/{origJs}". Then I call Java webscript using next url "testUrl2/testUrl/var1/var2". After that in Java code I remove "testUrl2" and construct WebScriptRequestURLImpl object with "/testUrl/var1/var2" url.

Comment: But when i create WebScriptRequestURLImpl  I need create Match object with templateUrl and templateVars. But how to get: 1) templateUrl for "/testUrl/var1/var2" if js webscript has more than one urls? 2) how to get templateVars from "/testUrl/var1/var2" for js webscript? Thank you.

Comment: You're missing the main remark I made: *avoid* calling a web script from within a web script controller, it doesn't make any sense. It's like sending an email to your siamese twin brother.

Comment: I wrote simple proxy webscript. Ok, I found resolution solution for my problem. I get Match object from request, not construct - 
<code>req.getRuntime().getContainer().getRegistry().findWebScript(method, url);</code>
Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course skuro is correct saying it is a bad idea going through the HTTP layer twice.

But in fact, executing **both**, a script controller and a java method is supported by Alfresco right out of the box - without ugly hacks, and without passing the entire HTTP layer twice.

You may do this:

Put your script code in the corresponding .js file.

Make sure your Java class is a subclass of `DeclarativeWebScript`, override `executeImpl` and put your custom logic there.

Sure, you can still argue that having two controllers is bad style. :)