# XML Syntax error when processing JSON output for atom feed in Alfresco webscript

Tags: json, alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I've run into an incredibly very frustrating error. This was working without issue on Friday and I deployed it last night, found out today that the modified timestamp isn't properly formatted for iso8690 (the application which digests the feed is very strict) so I reformatted it and built a jar for testing. This error comes up:

```
05110009 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/site-webscripts/org/foo/components/dashlets/recent-docs.get.js': 05110008 SyntaxError: illegally formed XML syntax (jar:file:/usr/share/tomcat6/shared/lib/recent-docs.jar!/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/foo/components/dashlets/recent-docs.get.js#20(eval)#1)
```

So I revert the changes and the exact same error is displayed. Can anyone tell me why I'm receiving this? I even copied the original jar back in, same error.

Here's an example of the JSON output generated by the repo webscript:

```json
{
"documents": 
    [
        {
            "site": "swsdp",
            "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/1a0b110f-1e09-4ca2-b367-fe25e4964a4e",
            "id": "1a0b110f-1e09-4ca2-b367-fe25e4964a4e",
            "name": "Project Contract.pdf",
            "title": "Project Contract for Green Enery",
            "creator": "abeecher",
            "description": "Conract for the Green Energy project",
            "categories": [
                    ],
            "created": "15 Feb 2011 21:26:54 PM (UTC)",
            "modified": "14 Jun 2011 10:28:54 AM (UTC)"
        },
        {
            "site": "swsdp",
            "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/05dedd34-9d9d-48d9-9af6-c81b555541c9",
            "id": "05dedd34-9d9d-48d9-9af6-c81b555541c9",
            "name": "WebSiteReview.mp4",
            "title": "WebSiteReview.mp4",
            "creator": "abeecher",
            "description": "This is a video of the mock up to show the planned structure for the new web site.",
            "categories": [
                    ],
            "created": "08 Mar 2011 10:35:10 AM (UTC)",
            "modified": "08 Mar 2011 10:37:43 AM (UTC)"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the share webscript stuff

`recent-docs.get.desc.xml`

```
  <shortname>Recently Modified Documents</shortname>

  <description>Retrieve Recently Modified content for a site</description>

  <url>/components/recent-docs?site={site}</url>

  <arg>

    <shortname>site</shortname>

    <description><![CDATA[site name]]></description>

  </arg>

  <format default="html">argument</format>

  <authentication>user</authentication>

  <transaction>required</transaction>

  <cache>

    <neverCache>false</neverCache>

    <mustRevalidate/>

  </cache>

</webscript>
```

`recent-docs.get.js`

```
function main()

{

    for (var arg in args)

    {

      if (arg == "site")

      {

        model.site = args[arg];

      }

    }

        // call the repository to get recent documents

        var connector = remote.connect("alfresco"); 

        var json = connector.call("/recent-docs?site=" + escape(model.site));

        if (json.status == 200)

        {

                obj = eval("(" + json + ")");

                model.docs = obj["documents"];

        }

        else

        {

                obj = eval("(" + json + ")");

                obj.name = "Error";

                model.docs = obj;

        }



}



main();
```

`recent-docs.get.atom.ftl`

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

  <generator version="${server.version}">Alfresco (${server.edition})</generator>

  <link rel="self" href="${absurl(url.full)?xml}" />

  <id>${absurl(url.full)?xml}</id>

  <title>Site: ${site}</title>

  <subtitle>Alfresco Recently Modified Documents</subtitle>  

  <updated>${xmldate(date)}</updated>

  <icon>${absurl(url.context)}/res/themes/default/images/app-logo-48.png</icon>

<#list docs as child>

  <entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>

    <title>${child.name?html}</title>

    <link href="${absurl(url.context)}/page/document-details?nodeRef=${child.nodeRef}"/>

    <id>urn:uuid:${child.id}</id>

    <updated>${child.modified}</updated>

    <summary>

         ${msg("feed.uploaded", child.name, child.creator)}<br />

     <#if child.modifier?exists>${msg("feed.modified", child.modified, child.modifier)}<br /></#if>

     ${child.description!""}<br />

     <#if child.categories[0]?exists>

     ${msg("feed.categories")} <#list child.categories as category> ${category.name}<#if category_has_next>, </#if></#list></#if><br />

     </summary>

    <author> 

      <name>${child.creator}</name>

    </author> 

  </entry>

</#list>

</feed>
```

I've been hacking at this trying various things without success, I've got a set of changes to correct the atom template so it's a valid atom document but i need to figure out why this error is showing up. I think it's because I'm not converting everything to a string in the repo webscript (only modified/creation time) but it's not clear how I should prepare it.

**Update** I modified the atom template to run on the repo side and the result is XML valid so at least that's working. On the share side I'm still seeing the syntax error which is problematic as I plan to build a dashlet with this.

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the xml output of the FTL, and running it through an XML validator to check if it's really correct or not?

Comment: Yeah, I previously thought it was valid but I didn't realise it was just halting on the first error (complained about the encodingtag). I also wrote an html template that should work. It doesn't matter which format I use as the same error is generated.

Comment: I modified the atom template to run on the repo side and the result is XML valid so at least that's working. On the share side I'm still seeing the syntax error which is problematic as I plan to build a dashlet with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call js webscript from Java webscript in Alfresco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109901/call-js-webscript-from-java-webscript-in-alfresco)